# RabbitMQ Messaging In Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, package, messaging, rabbitmq

I need to use RabbitMQ to publish and subscribe to queues **in Node.js**

I already done it in Ruby but I need to do the work in Node.js and I don't find any resource.

Is there any method ? or Library to make it use ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the AMQP library for node. On github: http://github.com/postwait/node-amqp#readme, and in npm:

```
$ npm install amqp
```

Comment: Thank you very much. AMQP was exactly what I needed and not really RabbitMQ for this application.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at [rabbit.js](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/11/12/rabbitmq-nodejs-rabbitjs/) which provides a socket-oriented API for node.js with the rabbitMQ back-end.

Answer (score 0):

you can use amqp library.

```
npm install amqp
```

small tutorial on rabbitmq official website: [amqp hello world node.js example](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html)